# Count/sort all letters in a string with a stream in Java (ignoring numbers)

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

My friend says this is not possible, but I believe she is wrong. Assume I have a list of strings made of alphanumeric characters:

"aa1, aaaa, aaa, a12, a5, 44a44, 3232aa"

I want to write a stream that will:

- look at each individual element
- identify count all of the letters (ignoring numbers)
- if the number is odd, do x
- if the number is even, do y

She says that this will result in terminal operations within the stream (count) and it's not possible. I looked online and, after starting, my thought was it would be easier to just filter out all the even ones. I ended up with this:

```
List<String> evaluateStrings = validChars.stream().filter(x -> x.replaceAll("\\d","").length() %2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this doesn't even filter out all the numbers.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Do x and y result in a string that you want to collect? What exactly is the final desired result?

Comment: Are you starting with a `String` object or a list of strings? Your prose does not match your example data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the map function to remove the numbers.

I would highly recommend filtering before the map to check for null strings, otherwise you might somehow get a null pointer exception (NPE). I highly stress filtering out null values when using streams and transforming data, it will save you lots of trouble in the future as you start streaming different data types from different sources.

```
List<String> evaluateStrings = validChars.stream()
// transform the data in the stream, remove numeric chars
.map(x -> x.replaceAll("\\d",""))
// Filter to allow even length strings
.filter(x -> x.length() %2 == 0)
// Collect the transformed and filtered results.
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to collect all your strings into a collection, while both doing x and why depending on even or oddness:

```
List<String> evaluateStrings = validChars.stream()
// transform the data in the stream, remove numeric chars
.map(x -> x.replaceAll("\\d","")
// Filter to allow even length strings
.map(x -> {
      if(x.length() %2 == 0) {
        //if number is even, do x
        return doY(x);
      } else {
        // If number is odd, do y
        return doX(x);
      }
})
// Collect the transformed and filtered results.
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This code fails with most characters. The `String#length` method is legacy, failing with characters outside the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).

Comment: The Char type is legacy, String's length is not legacy and has no indications in the Javadoc (At least OpenJDK 17) that it is legacy. According to the comments in the source for String: Returns the length of this string.  The length is equal to the number of Unicode code units</a> in the string. In the context of the user's question, they specifically stated alphanumeric characters, not special characters or non-English characters. This code will work for the use cases that the answer is intended for.

Comment: `"".length()` returns `2`. That is not what a calling programmer expects or deserves. This happens with the majority of characters. I'd call that “legacy”, if in a generous mood. The modern replacement is simple enough: `"".codePoints().count()` returns `1`. I do not understand this defensiveness over troubled flawed features. The same desperate defenses were made for the terrible `Date`/`Calendar` classes as well.

Comment: @BasilBourque,  Did you miss the "alpha-numeric" part? It's not legacy until it's not meant to be used anymore. But yes, your example shows a good point in terms of things people commonly use in "language". If you are developing an application that does not use the emoji language part, then String.length() is just fine. If you're building a mobile messaging application, then you are absolutely correct.

Comment: Nothing about the `String` class was ever documented to be restricted to certain characters. The class was intended to handle Unicode text, all Unicode text, not English text, not ASCII text. Unfortunately the implementation turned out to be brittle and could not keep up with the evolution in Unicode. The `char` type is legacy, as I said. The Java team at Sun readily admitted this. The situation was ameliorated in Java 5+ with the addition of code point methods to `String`, `StringBuilder`, `Character`, etc. Time to move on. Learning to use code point integers is really not that difficult.

Comment: `if(x.length() %2 == 0) { … }` becomes `if(x.codePoints().count() %2 == 0) { … }` to run successfully with all text rather than breaking on occasion.

Comment: I do appreciate you bringing up the codePoints example, it does bring clarity. I tend to handle text-only data that does not use anything outside of unicode, so I have not ran into the case you demonstrated. The one thing I have ran into is problems with legacy Dates, which have been a bane of my existence.

Comment: Just as the `Date`/`Calendar` disaster was replaced with *java.time* classes, I hope someday the text-handling facilities in Java are revamped. I'm waiting for Brian Goetz, Mark Reinhold, et al. to launch a *Project Papyrus*. In the meantime, we can get by with the `codePoint…` methods.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, possible

> My friend says this is not possible, but I believe she is wrong

Yes, she is wrong. You can accomplish all that in a single line of code using streams.

### Code points

Avoid the `char`/`Character` type in Java, as it has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters.

Your Question is not clear. I am guessing that the result of “do x” and “do y” is a string that you want to collect.

Below is some example code.

### `Stream#map`

We use `Stream#map` to transform each word of the input into a count of its letters after filtering out code points representing digits or other non-alphabetic characters.

We use a ternary operator to call either the method for even numbers or the method for odd numbers. Both methods return a `String` object. We collect those returned `String` objects in a list.

```java
List < String > results = 
    Arrays
    .stream(
        "aa1, aaaa, aaa, a12, a5, 44a44, 3232aa"
        .split( ", " )
    )
    .map(
        string -> 
            string
            .codePoints()  // Returns an `IntStream`
            .filter( Character :: isAlphabetic ) // Eliminate digits, punctuation, etc.
            .count()      // Count how many alphabetic characters found in that word.
            % 2 == 0      // Use modulo to test for even number.
            ?             // Ternary operator. 
                doEven()  // returns a `String` object.
            : 
                doOdd()   // returns a `String` object.
    )
    .toList()
;
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/s6Rc8y).

> [even, even, odd, odd, odd, odd, even]